# how to create view like gallery

Tags: android

How can i create exact view like as below image? Image which are used for next and previous here are imagebuttons?please give me idea for this.

[image: Gallery view in emulator]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use a `ViewFlipper` to display your image and similarly as you click on the left or right button you can change the image correspondingly.

To begin with `ViewFlipper` you can use these below links,

http://android-journey.blogspot.com/2009/12/android-viewflipper-and-slidingdrawer.html

https://github.com/ivansf/ViewFlipper-Demo

Or you can go for `ImageSwitcher`. And sample tutorials are given here,

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/ImageSwitcher1.html

http://saigeethamn.blogspot.com/2010/05/image-switcher-view-android-developer.html